# How to print request body using spring-test-mvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm using spring-test-mvc to test my controller, but I can't find a way to print request body which is very inconvenient.

with MockMvcResultHandlers.print()

```
mvc.perform(put("/payment/1234")
    .content("{\"amount\":2.3")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andDo(print());
```

I found some body information but don't find the body part:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = PUT
     Request URI = /payment/1234
      Parameters = {}
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}

         Handler:
            Type = com.restbucks.ordering.rest.PaymentResource
          Method = public org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<com.restbucks.ordering.domain.Payment> com.restbucks.ordering.rest.PaymentResource.handle(com.restbucks.ordering.commands.MakePaymentCommand)

           Async:
   Async started = false
    Async result = null
```

*Update*

After reading some source codes, it seems that I should extends MockMvcResultHandlers to add some print items?

```
//PrintingResultHandler.java
protected void printRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    this.printer.printValue("HTTP Method", request.getMethod());
    this.printer.printValue("Request URI", request.getRequestURI());
    this.printer.printValue("Parameters", getParamsMultiValueMap(request));
    this.printer.printValue("Headers", getRequestHeaders(request));
    // add body print?
}
```

*Update*
Proof of Concept codes:

```
public static class CustomMockMvcResultHandlers {

    public static ResultHandler print() {
        return new ConsolePrintingResultHandler();
    }


    /**
     * Have to copy this class from spring
     */
    private static class ConsolePrintingResultHandler extends PrintingResultHandler {

        public ConsolePrintingResultHandler() {
            super(new ResultValuePrinter() {

                @Override
                public void printHeading(String heading) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(String.format("%20s:", heading));
                }

                @Override
                public void printValue(String label, Object value) {
                    if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()) {
                        value = CollectionUtils.arrayToList(value);
                    }
                    System.out.println(String.format("%20s = %s", label, value));
                }


            });


        }

        @Override
        protected void printRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            super.printRequest(request);
            getPrinter().printValue("Body", getContentAsString(request));
        }

        private String getContentAsString(MockHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String aux;

            while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(aux);
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the request or response?

Comment: @M.Deinum request. And the response print is out of box now.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this will now be possible with Spring Framework 5.0 M3:

> The print() and log() methods in Spring MVC Test now print the request body if the character encoding has been set in the mock request.

Based on [this Jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14717)

Also mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-the-Spring-Framework#testing-improvements)

Comment: I don't forget to first call MockHttpServletRequestBuilder#characterEncoding, otherwise the print() or log() won't work